# get frozen map of cassandra in scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have following Cassandra table schema :-

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id text,
stats frozen<map<text, text>> )
```

I created scala application to extract the data from cassandra and after some manipulation will again update the data to cassandra.

```
val result =  session.execute("Select * from test where id= 'testid'")
val resultList = result.all()
val rows = resultList.iterator()

if (resultList.size() > 0) {
 while (rows.hasNext()) {
   val curRow = rows.next()
   val ID = curRow.getString("id")
   val statistics = curRow.getMap[String,String] ??????
 }
}
```

Data row in cassandra table is like this :-

```
('testid',{'a1': '10', 'a2': '0', 'a3': '0', 'a4': '22', 'd1': '0', 'd2': '1', 'd3': '1', 'd4': '0', 'exb': '0', 'inb': '6', 'satno': '10'})
('id123',{'a1': '10', 'a2': '0', 'd1': '0', 'd2': '1', 'd3': '1', 'd4': '0'})
```

I want to exactly map my stats field into statistics. How should I do this my fields in stats column is dynamic for 1 row it may have 10 key value pairs for other row , it may have 7 key value pairs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write it as following:

```
val statistics = curRow.getMap[String,String]("stats", 
    classOf[String], classOf[String])
```

For example,

```
val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build()
val session = cluster.connect()

val result =  session.execute("Select * from test.fmtest where id= 'id123'")
val resultList = result.all()
val rows = resultList.iterator()

if (resultList.size() > 0) {
  while (rows.hasNext()) {
    val curRow = rows.next()
    val ID = curRow.getString("id")
    val statistics = curRow.getMap[String,String]("stats", 
        classOf[String], classOf[String])
    println("id=" + ID + ", stats=" + statistics)
  }
}
cluster.close()
```

will print:

```
id=id123, stats={a1=10, a2=0, d1=0, d2=1, d3=1, d4=0}
```

Comment: Ohh great, also how can I extract any particular key like "a1" or "d4" ?

Comment: then you just use normal Map operations on the `statistics` object

Comment: Thanks @Alex, it worked. I'am accepting your answer.